# Setup Keycloak on Azure with external Postgres DB

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, keycloak

I am trying to setup Keycloak server on Azure Web App in production mode with Postgres DB (DigitalOcean). I am not sure what are a correct steps

Hello everyone,
For days, I've been trying to deploy Keycloak (the latest version) on Azure Web App, but without success. I followed the documentation from their official website and simultaneously watched this YouTube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neHFkd8c-gc

However, I always seem to get stuck somewhere. The official website mentions a Dockerfile, while in Web App, I can only use Docker Compose. Currently, I have the site up and running, I have access to the web page, but I'm encountering an error in the console:
[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH85h.png)

Here are the other settings:

[AppConfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMcVi.png)

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOEwr.png)

How can I first make it work without a database and then switch to using a PostgreSQL database?
How can I execute commands on Keycloak once it's inside a container and in a Web App?
Should I use dockerfile, push to container registry and then use it with ContainerApp?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue with the console was resolved :) Now, I need to force Keycloak to use Postgres db.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to first get things working in a dev mode before attempting production settings. You can pull and run a docker container with keycloak with the following command. It uses a local h2 database.

docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.1 start-dev

Then you can go to the Keycloak console at  http://localhost:8080/admin and use admin/admin to login rather than running commands inside the container.

Reference: https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker

You can get your configuration correct and then later deploy it in production mode in Azure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).